# Multipart-config conflict between @Path and @WebServlet

Tags: java, file-upload, multipart

Hello i have to upload a file to my server so 
I'm trying to use @MultipartConfig  the way the docs says

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm

so i have a myweb.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>BudgetsWs</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myPackage.BudgetWs</servlet-class> // where my class is
        <multipart-config>
              <location>/tmp</location>
              <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
              <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
              <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
         </multipart-config>
 </servlet>
```

and my class with an annotation like this :

```
  @WebServlet("/budgets")
  @MultipartConfig
  public class BudgetsWs{
  ....
  }
```

but i already have (defines properly in web.xml):

```
  @Path("/budgets")
  public class BudgetsWs{
  ....
  }
```

The objectives , keeping the multipart-config in web.xml and having the class like this:

```
  @MultipartConfig
  @Path("/budgets")
  public class BudgetsWs{
  ....
  }
```

So the problem is that i can't figure a way to use @MultipartConfig ***without*** the annotation of @WebServlet, and ***only with*** @Path.

My conclusion for now is that i can't use @MultipartConfig with @Path annotation.

Am i right and so i have to search for another method? Or am i missing something important from the documentation?

Comment: `@MultipartConfig` is a servlet annotation. `@Path` is a Jax RS annotation.

Comment: Thanks i understand now. I'v resolved my problem since last week without @MultipartConfig. But it were confused for me to make the difference between servlet annotation and JaxRs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sotirios Delimanolis said

> @MultipartConfig is a servlet annotation. @Path is a Jax RS annotation